# Conditional Label formatting in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I am having troubles labeling my map. I have fire occurrences in some regions in my map and I only want them to be labeled and the other regions with no fire to stay without a label.

I want all the (CAD_names) to appear if only (cadastral_1 > 0) and to be labeled (check image) I tried using "case when" and other stuff but it did not work. Here is my attribute table:

[image: here is my attribute table]

Answer (score 10):

You have several options to achieve this.

You can label all features using an expression, and instruct to print the `CAD_names` or `Null` based on your condition:

```
if  ("cadastral_1" > 1,"CAD_names",null)
```

[image]

Another option is to use Ruled Based Labeling, and to create a rule for when `"cadastral_1" > 1`

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use rule-based labeling for that.

1. Right click on your layer and go to Layer properties
2. Go to labels
3. Select Rule-Based Labeling from the drop-down menu.
4. Add a new rule using the + icon
5. Next to filter, click the ... icon.  [image]
6. In the expression builder, expand the fields and values section
7. Create filter rule `"cadastral_1">0`  and close the expression builder
8. Select the field you want to display as label (CAD_names) [image]

Done